# Calling Wikitude SimpleIRExample from another project

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality, segmentation-fault, wikitude

I'm trying to integrate the SimpleIRExample as library into my project. For posting purposes, I wrote a minimal example which throws the same error as in my project.

The parent project 'TestIR' has to be like that (this is the MainActivity):

```
package com.example.testir;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import es.wul4.ar.WikitudeAR;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

context = this;

Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WikitudeAR.class); // HERE IS THE CALL TO WIKITUDE SIMPLEIREXAMPLE
context.startActivity(intent);
}
});
}
}
```

Parent project has this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testir"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testir.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="es.wul4.ar.WikitudeAR"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
  android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here comes the problem. I add the SimpleIRExample as library project in my parent project:

http://www.nacho-alvarez.es/descargas/simpleirexample_as_library.png

Here is the libs tree for SimpleIRExample:

```
.
├── armeabi
│   ├── libExtensionVuforia.so
│   └── libQCAR.so
├── armeabi-v7a
│   ├── libExtensionVuforia.so
│   └── libQCAR.so
├── javadoc.jar
├── QCAR.jar
└── wikitudesdk.jar
```

And the  section on SimpleIRExample manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".WikitudeAR"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

We have no syntax nor compile errors, so run the program. A simple button of my testIR project's activity appears, and when I pushed it I've got the following errors, in a repeatedly way:

**D/dalvikvm(27351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.testir/libarchitect.so 0x421a9cb0
D/dalvikvm(27351): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.testir/libarchitect.so 0x421a9cb0
A/libc(27351): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 27351 (.example.testir)**

When I create a main activity in a not-library in a standalone project, and call the WikitudeAR Activity, it works correctly. However, if the project uses several libraries, I've got same errors as above (Fatal signal 11 SIGSEV). It's interesting for me to have SimpleIRExample as library or call in any way, because I wrote an apps container that calls several libraries or modules to make a great and diverse app.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved installing new SDK version 3.0 launched yesterday (06/18/13). Now works perfectly as library in a Nexus 4 with Android 4.2.2, making some changes in the very good examples available of this version.

http://developer.wikitude.com/download